# How to get Unique identification of machine using JAVA?

Tags: java

i have developed one software.i need create licence for software that should not be run in any other machine. earlier i have used MAC address but it changes when machine is formatted.please help me to get permanent unique address.

Comment: You will never be able to generate or find a unique identifier for a computer that is a) portable across multiple OS and/or b) will survive a computer rebuild.  Your only option is to distribute a piece of hardware that must be installed in every machine (perhaps a variation of a usb drive) that contains a unique identifier.  That is also not great because the user could move the hardware item between computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows OS You can use the motherboard ID for the purpose using WMI, through a COM bridge such as [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)

Or alternately refer [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0580.html)

Comment: These solutions are Windows-only.